# Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie booting, but no HDMI output. Tried most suggestions on the forums

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hdmi

`How do I know the PI has booted?`

I connected my Pi via an RJ45 to my router and was able to SSH into it.

`What suggestions have I followed?`

I tried changing the settings in the config.txt. Mixed and matched everything as suggested here on StackExchange and on the offical forums.

`Is it possible that the cable is at fault?`

Not likely, since I tried 2 cables, one of which is an expensive cable.

Any ideas as to what could be going on here? Please let me know if you need any other information that I could provide.

Here is the output of my current config.txt:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
```

I've tried enabling the `hdmi_safe` mode on too, without any results.

Here is the output of `tvservice -s`

```
state 0x12000a [HDMI CEA (16) RGB lim 16:9], 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

Comment: "I tried changing the settings in the config.txt" We are supposed to guess which of the "suggestions" (mostly wrong) you have tried? Post the file and output of `tvservice -s`

Comment: The output of `tvservice` indicates the Pi is outputting HDMI (and the resolution). I would have to check but you should not need `hdmi_mode=1`. Whatever problem you have it does not seem to be the Pi.

Comment: See also http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Comment: @Milliways: Thanks, I'll look into it, although I imagine my monitor is at fault here. Can't verify it since my laptop does not output HDMI. I'd probably go with a headless OS and SSH instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was really silly on my part. But turns out the problem was that my monitor was not configured to take HDMI input. I had to go to the monitor settings and ask it to switch input mode to HDMI from DVI and it worked.

Like Milliways mentions in the comments above, running `tvservice -s` will show if the Raspberry Pi is outputting HDMI. If the output is correct, looking at your monitor config might be the next step forward.